# Trabajar sobre undefined

Tags: javascript

Resulta que tengo un objeto que parte siendo `undefined` para luego ir sumándole 1 hasta llegar a la id del objeto. Lo que pasa es que no puedo detectar si es `undefined` porque no me permite usarlo: me dice `undefined` (y quiero saber si es `undefined`).

Les dejo mi código:

```
function isKeyExists(obj,key){
    if( obj[key].id == undefined ){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
function save_to(){
        
        obtener();
        if(strings==null){
            strings={};
        }
        
        palabra=1;
 
        if(Object.keys(strings).length===0) {
            localStorage.setItem("nombre",JSON.stringify(carrito));
            console.log(carrito);
        }
        else{
        let po = 1; 
        isKeyExists( strings,91 );
      /*  for (abc=0;abc<Object.keys(strings).length;abc++){
           
            just=strings[81  ].id;
        console.log (just);
          if (just==undefined){
            palabra=palabra+1;
            abc=abc-1;

          }
          else{
            abcd.push =( palabra );

            palabra=palabra+1;
          }
          
        }  */   }
```

Comment: Para comparar si la key es undefined, tienes que hacer solamente esto:  if( obj[key] === undefined )

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
if(typeof obj[key].id === 'undefined' )
```

Según la documentación de Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

> Se puede usar typeof. Recuerda que este siempre devolverá una cadena
> de texto. Una razón para usar typeof es que **no devuelve un error si la
> variable no fue declarada**.

Comment: Claro: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aprovecharte de las funcionalidades [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) & [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) de JS, donde en este caso **undefined** es **false**   Por lo tanto puedes hacer algo como `!!obj["key"].id` donde `!!` hace un [conversión implícita](https://mauriciogc.medium.com/javascript-ecuaciones-complejas-440578bcfad7) de `undefined` a `boolean`.

**Ojo!**

Debes tener cuidado con esto, ya que, en caso de que `obj["key"].id` sea igual a 0 La siguiente expresión: `!!0` retornara `false` al igual que `!!undefined` retornara `false` Por lo tanto esta solución seria viable siempre y cuando `obj["key"].id` sea mayor de 0

**Edit**: Vuelvo a leer el problema y me doy cuenta que lo que arroja `undefined` es `obj["key"]`. Por lo tanto, puedes aplicar lo mismo, pero sin usar el `id`, es decir: `!!obj["key"]`. Cabe añadir que en este caso, no tendrias el problema antes planteado, ya que, estarias comparando la existencia de un objeto/propiedad y no de un numero como en el caso de `obj["key"].id`.